# Use custom Microsoft login screens for office 365 SSO (through Azure AD)

Tags: c#, asp.net, single-sign-on, office365, ws-federation

I'm trying to implement Office 365 Single Sign On using WSFederation and I have built an ASP.NET MCV app according to [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151790.aspx).
It works to a degree; the user is directed to sign in to Azure AD and reaches the home page.

Some people who will use this app belong to companies who have their own custom Microsoft login pages- the user is redirected to these when they enter their email and press tab. If their login page is very customised, they then have to enter their email again. My question is this: is there a way to redirect the user to the custom login page automatically, since I already know which organisation they belong to?

I have tried changing the wsFederation homeRealm in the web.config to the organisation domain name, which ought to work but does not. It adds "&?whr=domain.org" (for example) to the end of the URL generated by the app. The reason it doesn't work is that when this URL is followed, Microsoft redirects the user to a slightly different address where they log in and the home realm (whr) parameter is lost.

Is there any way to automatically redirect to the organisation's login page? Or am I simply building the wrong type of app?

Thanks in advance,

LD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I seem to have answered my own question.

There are probably better ways, but this is what I did:
Using [*these instructions*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151789.aspx) I created a sign in controller and passed the url of the actual login page (which is different from the url generated by the app) into the Redirect function. I added a whr parameter to this and everything redirects properly.